# ViewModel generico para eventos del ratón WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Soy algo nuevo en **MVVM**. Estoy intentando crear un **ViewModel** genérico para gestionar todos los eventos del ratón, de mi aplicación y tener todo ese código centralizado. He visto varios ejemplos de **MVVM** pero la mayoría son clases muy complejas que al final lo único que hacen es llamar un método **void**.

Actualmente tengo un grupo de métodos en cada **View** que me gustaría centralizar en un **ViewModel** por motivos de mejorar el mantenimiento del sistema y no tener que ir a cada **View** para modificar el código.

---

## View

```
#region Eventos del Ratón

private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic control = sender as Image;
    if (control != null)
        control.OpacityMask = new SolidColorBrush { Opacity = 1, Color = Colors.Black };

    //...
}

private void MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //...
}

private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //...
}

#endregion
```

---

El problema es que no se como crear los comandos con parametros en el **ViewModel** y llamarlos en el **XAML** pasando como parametro el **sender**. Disculpen si es una pregunta muy basica es que soy nuevo en esto de **MVVM**.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme

Comment: No termino de entender tu pregunta. Si lo que quieres es gestionar esos eventos de ratón en todos tus viewmodels...por que no les metes en una clase y haces que todos tus viewmodels hereden de esta? Yo en mis proyectos tengo una clase `ViewModelBase` para meter el código común a todos los viewmodels y luego heredo de ella.

Comment: Disculpa es que como soy nuevo no se como crear los comandos con parametros y como llamarlos en el XAML.

Comment: O sea, a ver si entiendo. Tu problema es definir un comando con parámetros en el viewmodel y llamarlo desde tu xaml cuando se produce un evento de ratón? Si es así, yo editaría la pregunta y trataría de aclararla un poco mas...

Comment: creo que esta mas claro ahora.

Comment: Yo opinaba igual que la primer respuesta del thread que habias señalado antes.. y ahora opino, que en realidad no tenes que mandar eso al VM.. si no que deberias tener un control que ya lo haga solito...

Comment: por motivos de mejorar el mantenimiento del sistema y no tener que ir a cada **View** o **UserControl** para modificar el código.

Comment: Si estuviera en un user control, estaria en uno solo. los eventos de la vista, son manejados por la vista..si no, como testearias eso si estuviera en el vm? ademas, no entiendo porque haces dynamic control cuando sabes que es una imagen. y si no lo supieras, deberias chequearlo antes.

Comment: ese es el asunto los eventos son para animaciones y efectos de sonido y se aplicaran a diferentes controles, Grid, Image, Border, TexBox, etc...

Comment: Y todos los controles tiene el mismo efecto? o vas a tener un if kilometrico dentro de cada vm para saber que pasa con cada control? suena a una solucion rebuscada. Tal vez solo debas heredar a cada user control el tipo de control que queres y punto.. igual la solucion tambien es rebuscada en ese caso...

Comment: Crea un **ViewModel base**, donde tengas las funciones que vas a repetir en cada View. Ahora solo tienes que heredar de esa base los archivos que tengan esa funcionalidad. Puedes tener varios archivos base, o heredar varias veces según tu estructua. Lo bueno es que si un View hereda una función y no te interesa, de forma específica puedes sobreescribirla fácilmente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Te responderé como manejar ICommands con parámetros, para este ejemplo un botón que quita un item de un listbox (boton integrado dentro de un item de un listbox y se envía a sí mismo al comando).. tu adáptalo:

Primero crea esta clase (es genérica, vale para todo proyecto):

```
public class ParamCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public ParamCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = () => true;
    }

    public ParamCommand(Action<object> action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this._canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool result = this._canExecute.Invoke();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                _action(parameter);
            }
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

}
```

Luego si quieres llamar un comando desde un botón común:

```
<!-- Botón comun -->
 <Button Content="Quitar" 
 Command="{Binding EliminarArchivoCommand}" 
 CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Si el botón está dentro de un contenedor como un item de un ListBox, fíjate que el llamará primero al DataContext, y especificará el AncestorType de tipo ListBox y todo esto significa que usará el ICommand del datacontext del listbox que esté jerárquicamente mas arriba.. el botón al estar en un item de listbox no verá al viewmodel por si solo, pero si verá al control que lo contiene y a través de él verá el viewmodel.

```
<!-- Botón dentro de un item de un listbox -->
<Button 
Content="Quitar este item del listbox" 
Command="{Binding DataContext.EliminarItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Luego en tu ViewModel declaras el ICommand así:

```
private ICommand _eliminarArchivoCommand;
public ICommand EliminarArchivoCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_eliminarArchivoCommand == null)
        _eliminarArchivoCommand = new ParamCommand(new Action<object>(EliminarArchivo));
        return _eliminarArchivoCommand;
    }
}
```

Y el método sería así:

```
private void EliminarArchivo(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null) //Este object es el botón!!
        //aquí está tu boton
        MessageBox.Show(obj.GetType().Name); //Button
    }
}
```

Puedes usar entonces el boton y obtener su DataContext y properties

```
((Button)obj).Content
```

Pero como tu viewmodel es global podrías llamar al método con cualquier control, así que deberías identificar que control es el que llamó al comando, pero eso ya es otro problema, con un switch podrías.. pero la respuesta termina aquí.

```
switch(obj.GetType().Name)
{
    case "Button":

    break;
    case "Grid":

    break;
    default:
    break;
    }
```

AGREGO PARA COMENTARIO:

Para gestionar diferentes eventos de un mismo control lo puedes hacer así, por ejemplo el mismo ListBox:

Primero: Agrega el namespace arriba en XAML

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Lo puedes poner directo debajo de:

xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

Y luego en el control puedes gestionar todos sus eventos así:

```
<ListBox>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CargarItemSourceCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MostrarMenuContextualCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ActualizarAlgoCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

Si te fijas solo pones el nombre del evento, puedes poner todos los que quieras.

Un ejemplo con PasswordBox que además tiene un CommandParameter que es lo que preguntas más arriba.

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=tx_password}"/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Un ejemplo con un TextBlock que está dentro de un item de un ListBox donde nuevamente aparece el DataContext, que es indicador de que el control está dentro de otro control de tipo contenedor..

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CopiarTextoCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBlock}, Path=Text}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que en algunos controles tengo varios **Binding**, `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, `MouseLeftButtonDown` y `MouseLeftButtonUp`. ¿Puedo usar Command en el **XAML** para gestionar todos estos eventos?

Comment: Con el namespace interactivity se puede hacer, agrego esto a la respuesta.. es muy fácil

Comment: Debes agregar la Referencia System.Windows.Interactivity para usar Interactivity en XAML, revisa bien el código completo que le hice cambios y correcciones para que no te confundas en nada.

Un saludo.